# How to optimize with a same table join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have this table structure:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZc3n.png)

I need to find the distinct 'symbol' where the id_exchange are 1 and 7. I have this query with subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT symbol
FROM ohlcv 
WHERE 
    id_exchange=1 
    AND quote_currency='USDT' 
    AND symbol IN (SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM ohlcv WHERE id_exchange=7 AND quote_currency='USDT');
```

It finds the desired data, but it is very slow.
Is there a way to optimize it, maybe doing an inner join with the same table?

Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***
I don't know what that count(symbol) was doing there, it wasn´t part of the original query, I just saw that mistake. I might have been doing some testing and copied the wrong one. Please forgive my mistake. :(

*** INDEX Structure ***
[Show index from ohlcv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzyX7.png)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378989/2469308

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you need distinct inside count as it will give you distinct symbol count.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT symbol)
FROM ohlcv
WHERE id_exchange IN (1,7)
  AND quote_currency='USDT'
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but took twice the time to execute and only brought the count, which by the way, didn´t match what was expected. In my original query I get 14 rows, the 14 that actually match quote_currency in both id_exchange. In this case I got a count of 102.

Answer (score 0):

Based on optimizing your existing query, you can do a self-join and put conditions in the ON clause instead of the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.symbol 
FROM ohlcv AS t1
INNER JOIN ohlcv AS t2 ON t2.id_exchange = 7 
WHERE 
    t1.id_exchange = 1 
    AND t1.quote_currency = 'USDT' 
    AND t2.quote_currency = 'USDT' 
    AND t1.symbol = t2.symbol
```

Comment: I tried this approach with your sentence, this is what I thought would be the solution, but it took so long that I killed the query after 50 minutes.

Comment: @demoniodojo Can you share indexing details on your tables. I believe that you may not have any indexing done.

Comment: Done! Added the index details.

Comment: @demoniodojo Please add a composite index (id_exchange, quote_currency, symbol) on the table. And rerun my query (I have edited based on your question description edit!)

Comment: @demoniodojo edited again! Check the latest query. Run it before adding composite index, and let me know how does it behave. Also, if possible, please share Explain statement results

Comment: Well, when I tried that query it ran for about 6 hours and never finished. I had to kill it. ;)
I´ll try tomorrow and post the Explain results.
Thank you!